# pycharm find functions with same name

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using pycharm to debug python code written by different authors.

The code is functional, there are no classes in use.

I was looking for a function usage and I have found out that name of the function is repeated on different modules of the project with different results.

It works because the use they import the file file.py and then reference the funciton as the following:

```
import file
(...)
aux = file.function_name(parameters)
```

Is there a way to find function name coincidences?

Comment: `import inspect; set(filter(inspect.isfunction, dir(module1))).intersection(filter(inspect.isfunction, dir(module2)))` would find matching function names from 2 different modules named `module1` and `module2`.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you know the name of the function in question:**

1. Use the 'Find in Path' function.

   - Edit > Find > Find in Path
   - or Right Click folder in project > Find in Path
2. Then search for a definition of the function you're looking for.

You can see my example I have the same function name in two different modules.
[image]

Comment: I don't know if there are functions with same name. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: Ahh, you want a 'find duplicates' when it comes to the function name.

Comment: `find duplicates`would be perfect but I'm unable to locate such function.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit.  I was putting quotes around the idea.  To my knowledge there isn't a function like that built-in.